# kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm

Tags: domain-controller, kerberos, samba4

I'm trying config samba4 as domain controller following [samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller#Installing_Samba)

/etc/resolv.conf :

```
domain transbekk.lan
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.254
```

/etc/hostname :

```
domain.transbekk.lan
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = TRANSBEKK
    realm = TRANSBEKK.LAN
    netbios name = DOMAIN
    server role = active directory domain controller
    dns forwarder = 192.168.1.1,192.168.1.254
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/transbekk.lan/scripts
    read only = No

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
```

/etc/krdb5.conf

```
  [libdefaults]
    default_realm = TRANSBEKK.LAN
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

When I have tried to test kerberos configuration (kinit administrator) an error occur:

> kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "TRANSBEKK.LAN" while getting initial credentials

Please what is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: You most likely skipped a step (or several). Go back to the wiki and compare what you were doing to what's present there.

Comment: sure, but i don't see where

Comment: can you share what version of samba you used that correct you issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, It was a winbind issue with this version.
Laster samba's version resolves my problem.